# PhantomJS много post запросов

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Нужна помощь при работе с phantomjs. Есть функция:

```
function auth(url, login, password)
      {
      var page = require("webpage").create();
      var post_data = 'login=' + login + '&password=' + password;
      page.open(url, 'post', post_data, function(status) {
        if (status !== 'success')
        {
          phantom.exit();
        }
        else
        {
          return page.plainText;
        }
     }); 
    }

console.log(auth(url, 'login', '12345'));
```

Дело в том, что функция вернёт undefined вместо содержимого страницы page. Как сделать так, чтобы возвращалось содержимое страницы? И чтобы можно было повторно вызвать данную функцию в коде дальше, чтобы всё работало на ура? Есть какие-то варианты?

Comment: я заменил return page.plainText; на set_post_result(page.plainText); и создал функцию function set_post_result(result_data)
{
  return result_data;
}

Comment: Если вместо return result_data прописать console.log(result_data) то выводит значение, но опять же не выводит return result_data, а пишет undefined

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73751/discussion-on-question-by-warfire-phantomjs--post-).

Comment: А теперь дочитай ответ до конца и пойми, что так, как ты хочешь, не заработает.

Comment: Если у тебя есть вариант решения, поделись.

Comment: Что значит, так как я хочу, не заработает? Если вариант с функцией никак нельзя заставить заработать, то объясните, почему? А как тогда заработает? Варианты по линку от D-side пробовал, проблема та же осталась. Варианты работают только с console.log(), а для return значения нет!

Comment: Сам, пока что, не могу разобраться, поэтому прошу, помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачку.

Comment: Предложите хоть какой-то вариант решения. Главное, чтобы работало по условиям выше.

Comment: Для return значения нет и не будет. Почему - подробно описано в ответе по ссылке.